# Creating dynamic mongodb pipeline from URL query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, syntax

I have a ***express*** route handling a request for resources in a collection and querying them against some dynamic criteria (whether it's included or not).

Currently, my code reflects some bad practice but I'm not exactly sure how to write it any dryer.

A summary of the code is as follows:

```
function generate_pipeline() {
    let { text, tags, paths, omit, featured, min_budget, max_budget, pagenation} = arguments[0];
    let pipeline = []; 
     if (text...tags...etc) {
        let item_after_manipulation = foo.bar(item)
        let stage = {$match: { item }}
        pipeline.push(stage)
     } ........more if statements
}
```

I have these if statements for all of the arguments listed at the top of the function.

Is there any way to **dynamically** update my aggregation pipeline while keeping the logic needed to manipulate the objects before insertion and **not** have to use many if statements?

Comment: checkout builder pattern

Comment: @joyBlanks not sure what this means but I appreciate it.